# Comparison of Wronskian at three different points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $P$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ and $W$ the Wronskian of two linearly independent solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ of the ODE:
>   $$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+(1+x^2)\dfrac{dy}{dx}+ P(x)y=0,x\in\mathbb R$$
>   Let $W(1)=a,W(2)=b$ and $W(3)=c$, then
>
> 1. $a<0$ and $b>0$
> 2. $a<b<c$ or $a>b>c$
> 3. $\frac a{|a|}=\frac b{|b|}=\frac c{|c|}$
> 4. $0<a<b$ and $b>c>0$

*Attempt:*

By Abel's identity, for ODE $$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)=0$$  with solutions $y_1,y_2$
$$W_{(y_1,y_2)}(x)=W_{(y_1,y_2)}(x_0)e^{-\int\limits_{x_0}^xp(\zeta)d\zeta}$$

Playing around, let $x_0=1$, $p(x)=(1+x^2)$
$$W_{(y_1,y_2)}(2)=ae^{-\frac{10}3}=b$$ and 
$$W_{(y_1,y_2)}(3)=ae^{-\frac{32}3}=c$$

*Observations:*

1. $a,b,c$ are of same sign, depending on sign of $a$ - either positive or negative
2. $a<b<c$ or $a>b>c$ depending on sign of $a$

Suggesting 2 and 3 are the right options.

*Doubts:*

1. Am I correct in choosing $x_0=1$ ([since the theorem says *for every $x_0\in I$*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_identity#Statement_of_Abel.27s_identity))? If not, how is $x_0$ chosen?
2. If my choice of $x_0$ is wrong, am right in guessing that the observations I made stand with the correct $x_0$?
3. DE being one of my weak points: did I go wrong somewhere else/in observations I made?

Comment: Are you sure 'and' is correct in 2.? (because $a$ cannot be simultaneously be larger and smaller than $b$)

Comment: @FritsVeerman, true! Typo! Will fix now!

Comment: Ok, then to address your doubts: 1. Yes, you are absolutely free and correct to do that. As you've already observed, Abel's identity holds for every $x_0 \in I$, so in particular for $x_0 = 1$. Choosing $x_0=1$ as you did enables you to quickly obtain the relations you found between $a$, $b$ and $c$. The observations you made actually hold for any choice of $x_0$: just write $\int_{x_0}^2 = \int_{x_0}^1 + \int_1^2$ and go from there. I can't see anything going wrong in the steps you've taken.

Comment: @FritsVeerman, Thank you! Can you post it as an answer? I wish not to leave it unanswered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing your doubs:

1. Yes, you are absolutely free and correct to do that. As you've already observed, Abel's identity holds for every $x_0 \in I$, so in particular for $x_0 = 1$. Choosing $x_0 = 1$ as you did enables you to quickly obtain the relations you found between $a$, $b$ and $c$.
2. The observations you made actually hold for any choice of $x_0$: just write $\int_{x_0}^2 p(\zeta)\,\text{d}\zeta = \int_{x_0}^1 p(\zeta)\,\text{d}\zeta + \int_1^2 p(\zeta)\,\text{d}\zeta $ and go from there.
3. I can't see anything going wrong in the steps you've taken.

Comment: Thank you! :-) Just wanted to confirm!